# promise is not working on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have try following code but it's not working well I put logger in both method to check which method execution finish but call `addPersonalData` method as per logger.

```
var promisePersonal = removePersonalData(profile);
promisePersonal.then(
    addPersonalData(personal, profile)
);

function removePersonalData(profile) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var id = profile._id;
        Personal.remove({
            parent_id: id
        }, function(error) {
            if (!error) {
                logger.info('Personal Remove : success');
                resolve(profile);
            } else {
                logger.error('Personal Remove : error' + error);
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Logger :

```
12: 22: 45 PM - info: Inside addPersonalData mothod <----- //here is problem
12: 22: 45 PM - info: Profile saved: addPersonalData
12: 22: 45 PM - info: Enter into removeEducationData
12: 22: 45 PM - info: Number of Education data::2
12: 22: 45 PM - info: Inside addEducationData mothod
12: 22: 45 PM - info: Personal Remove: success <---- //here is problem this should be first execute
12: 23: 10 PM - info: Education Remove: success
```

what I make mistake in above code ? please give me your valuable advice to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is everything ok with `Promise`s you just using it wrong.
Try this:

```
var promisePersonal = removePersonalData(profile);
promisePersonal.then(function(profile) { 
    addPersonalData(personal, profile);
});

function removePersonalData(profile) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var id = profile._id;
        Personal.remove({
            parent_id: id
        }, function(error) {
            if (!error) {
                logger.info('Personal Remove : success');
                resolve(profile);
            } else {
                logger.error('Personal Remove : error' + error);
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: that's work :) can you elaborate `promise all` @ponury-kostek ?

Comment: Show some loop you iterate

Answer (score -1):

Please change the code as below. Hope it will help.

```
promisePersonal.then(
  () => addPersonalData(personal, profile) // callback function
)
```

Reason: Promise.then accepts a function but you have supplied a function call.